# java.lang.NullPointerException in following code?

Tags: android

i have two java classes of which one is activity class now from that activity class i want to call a functions of second class which is not an activity class.but when i call function GetRobotoRegularFont inside Font class its show me an error that "Caused by:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ojaswi.font.Font.GetRobotoRegularFont(Font.java:16)
at com.ojaswi.bookingscapemob.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:29)
```

"..the code for two java file is..please anyone help me answer..

code for first Java file

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

EditText email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTextUname);
    email.setTypeface(new Font().GetRobotoRegularFont());


}
```

}

code for second Java file

```
public class Font {

Typeface tf;
Context myContext;
public final Typeface GetRobotoRegularFont() {
    String fontPath = "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf";
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(myContext.getAssets(), fontPath);
    return tf;
}
```

}

Comment: Well, at least one variable is `null`.  You should do some debugging to determine which one!

Comment: Do you ever assign a value to `myContext` before calling the `GetRobotoRegularFont()` method? If not, then that's where you NPE comes from.

Comment: Your NullPointerException is on Line 16 of the Font class, please try to check all your variables on this line before posting your question here. I'm thinking that is your variable "myContext" which is null here. Have a look to Frank answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LoginActivity write this way

```
email.setTypeface(new Font().GetRobotoRegularFont(this));
```

And then in Font class

```
public class Font {

Typeface tf;
Context myContext;
public final Typeface GetRobotoRegularFont(Context context) {
    myContext = context;
    String fontPath = "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf";
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(myContext.getAssets(), fontPath);
    return tf;
}
```

Comment: but here we need to pass context parameter in GetRobotoRegularFont. correct.

Comment: Yes you are right. It was bymistake. I have corrected that.

Answer (score 3):

You never do set Context in the Font class.

Options:

- Add context to the constructor
- Add a setter method for the context field
- If you don't use the Font class in other places you can inline the code like Raghunandan did propose

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file is in assets folder you can do the following.

```
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/verdana.ttf");
 email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTextUname);
 email.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.BOLD);
```